# MySQL prepared statements result metadata

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, metadata

I have selective procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_d_test()
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  CONTAINS SQL
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM my_table;
END;
```

and I want to get metadata results (field names) using prepared statements

```
procedure TForm1.btnLowAPIClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LConn: Pointer;
  LSQL: AnsiString;
  LStmt: PMYSQL_STMT;
  LCnt: Integer;
  LFld: PMYSQL_FIELD;
  LRes: PMYSQL_RES;
begin
  LConn := MySQLInit;
  mysql_real_connect(LConn, 'localhost', 'root', '', 'test', 0, nil, CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS);
  MySQLQuery(LConn, 'SET character_set_results=ucs2');
  LSQL := 'CALL sp_d_test()';
  LStmt := mysql_stmt_init(LConn);
  if mysql_stmt_prepare(LStmt, PAnsiChar(LSQL), Length(LSQL)) <> 0 then
    MySQLStmtError(LStmt);
  if mysql_stmt_execute(LStmt) <> 0 then
    MySQLStmtError(LStmt);
  LCnt := mysql_stmt_field_count(LStmt);  // Returns corrected number
  LRes := mysql_stmt_result_metadata(LStmt);
  LFld := mysql_fetch_field(LRes);
  while LFld <> nil do begin
    LStr := UCS2BytesToUTF16(PByte(LFld^.name), LFld^.name_length);
    LFld := mysql_fetch_field(LRes);
  end;
end;
```

The fields `LFld^.name`, `LFld^.name_length` contains garbage. The field `LFld^.type` contains corrected type

If I do

```
MySQLQuery(LConn, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

then the field `LFld^.name` contains corrected value, but `LFld^.name_length` still contains garbage.

For simple select

```
LSQL := 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
```

The structure is filled correctly and for UCS2 and for UTF8. With one BUT. The documentation says

> char * name
>
> The name of the field, as a **null-terminated** string. If the field was given an alias with an AS clause, the value of name is the alias. For a procedure parameter, the parameter name.

For UCS2 the field `name` is **NOT** null-terminated, but name_length contains real size in bytes

Server version 5.1.41

Comment: Use a view instead of a procedure.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I must first perform some action with the data. I know a few ways to workaround, including the two queries: PROCEDURE + SELECT, but are interested in where my error in this code. Or is it a bug MySQL?